# Existence of Specific Regular Open Set in Topological Space

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to show that for any topological space $X$ and any $ O\subseteq X$ with $O$ an open set, there is an regular open set $W$ such that $ O \subseteq W$ and $O$ is dense in $W$.

I'm not quite sure what "$O$ is dense in $W$" means. Does this typically mean that $O$ is dense in the subspace topology induced by $W$ or for any nonempty open set contained in $W$, $O$ meets it?

I appreciate any clarification

Edit: I believe that I can just let $W = $ Int(Cl($O$)) as the regular open set, but I'm still trying to show the density part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of denseness is quite correct.

To show it for your suggestion $W= \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(O))$ : suppose $U$ is a non-empty open subset of $W$.

Suppose that $O \cap U=\emptyset$, it follows that $U \cap \operatorname{Cl}(O)=\emptyset$ too ($ O \subseteq U^\complement$, so $\operatorname{Cl}(O) \subseteq U^\complement$, as the right hand set is closed, so $U \cap \operatorname{Cl}(O) = \emptyset$), and so $U \cap \operatorname{Int}(\operatorname{Cl}(O)) = \emptyset$ as well, but this just says $U \cap W= \emptyset$, which cannot be as $\emptyset \neq U \subseteq W$ by assumption. So contradiction and thus $U \cap W \neq \emptyset$, QED.

Answer (score 3):

$O$ is dense in $W$ means that $O$ is dense in the subspace topology induced by $W$